Kotlin Volley Json get value
I've been working on this for some time and searching the internet, but I just can't find the solution.
I use volley to query an api and receive this response.
{

      "Title": "Groupname",
      "requestedURL": "url",
      "responseURL": [
            "https://i.mg.xxx/p372qxd3694e1.jpg",
            "https://i.mg.xxx/qs06k8e3694e1.jpg",
            "https://i.mg.xxx/mjfzw6e3694e1.jpg"
      ]

}

Title and requestedUrl are no problem
val responseName = response.getString("Title")

But I can't get the data from requestedURL.
I have tried various things with .getJSONArray / .getJSONObject - what I found on the internet, but nothing worked, maybe because I didn't understand it properly

Try: response.getJSONArray("responseURL") to get list of urls.

i tried. i dont get the data - is empty
